# What property ARFoundation Button has on Unity that enables it to perform a continuous task (Unlike onClick)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am looking for a property that enables a **UI touch button** to perform a continuous task unlike onClick which triggers an action once - when the press is released. Since I am trying to make a button that moves the object, I need something like onPress but this property is not defined.

If I understood the answer provided correctly, you should write two scripts one for the ContinuousButton class and the other for the desired actions. Here is my implementation following this answer:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Button))]
public class ContinuousButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    [SerializeField] private Button _button;
    // This will be called every frame while the button stays pressed
    public UnityEvent whilePressed;

    private Coroutine routine;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!_button) _button = GetComponent<Button>();
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        if (!_button.interactable) return;

        routine = StartCoroutine(WhilePressedRoutine());
    }

    public void OnPinterUp(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        if (routine != null) StopCoroutine(routine);
        routine = null;
    }

    public void OnPinterExit(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        if (routine != null) StopCoroutine(routine);
        routine = null;
    }

    private IEnumerator WhilePressedRoutine()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            whilePressed.Invoke();

            yield return null;
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        ((IPointerUpHandler)_button).OnPointerUp(eventData);
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        ((IPointerExitHandler)_button).OnPointerExit(eventData);
    }
}
```

......

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class ControlButtons : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private Button ClockwiseButton;
    [SerializeField]
    private Button ForwardButton;
    [SerializeField]
    private Button ReverseButton;
    [SerializeField]
    private Button AntiClockwiseButton;
    [SerializeField]
    private Button AscendButton;
    [SerializeField]
    private Button DescendButton;

    public GameObject objectToPlace;

    private void Awake()
    {
        ClockwiseButton.onClick.AddListener(() => objectToPlace.transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, Vector3.up, 20 * Time.deltaTime));
        //ForwardButton.onClick.AddListener(() => objectToPlace.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * 10));
        ForwardButton.GetComponent<ContinuousButton>().whilePressed.AddListener(() => objectToPlace.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * 10)); //Breaking from this point.
        ReverseButton.onClick.AddListener(() => objectToPlace.transform.Translate(Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime * 10));
        AntiClockwiseButton.onClick.AddListener(() => objectToPlace.transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, Vector3.up, -20 * Time.deltaTime));
        AscendButton.onClick.AddListener(() => objectToPlace.transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * 10));
        DescendButton.onClick.AddListener(() => objectToPlace.transform.Translate(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * 10));
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

But it didn't worked neither. Here is a video I made: As you can see I need to press the button for each move, and the aircraft doesn't moves constantly when I long press. Since I plan to upload my work for the Google Play Store, I'd love to know how I can introduce the desired behavior.
[Video of the app](https://youtu.be/upi4pm_dQwI?t=79)

Comment: Hi, I've seen that both of your questions were tagged [tag:UnityScript], please note that UnityScript is its own *deprecated* language that is no longer in use by Unity. As the tag information mentions it **is not** an over-encompassing term for any script in Unity. Unless you are working on legacy code using the actual UnityScript language please don't use that tag, but just use the [tag:C#] as that is the actual used language. I have removed the tags for you as the questions seem to be about C# (as also mentioned by your C# tag).

Answer (score 1):

Well .. such thing doesn't exist ;)

You can however easily implement your own by using the [`IPointerDownHandlet`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html), `IPointerUpHandler` and evtl also `IPointerExitHandler` interfaces:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Button))]
public class ContinuousButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    [SerializeField] private Button _button;
    // This will be called every frame while the button stays pressed
    public UnityEvent whilePressed;

    private Coroutine routine;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!_button) _button = GetComponent<Button>();
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        if(!_button.interactable) return;

        routine = StartCoroutine (WhilePressedRoutine());
    }  
    
    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        if(routine != null) StopCoroutine (routine);
        routine = null;
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        if(routine != null) StopCoroutine (routine);
        routine = null;
    }

    private IEnumerator WhilePressedRoutine ()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            whilePressed.Invoke();

            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Attach this to a `GameObject` with a `Button` component. Then reference the desired method in `whilePressed` as you would with the `onClick`.

Either via the Inspector or via code

```
yourButton.GetComponent<ContinuousButton>().whilePressed.AddListener(...);
```

---

**Update**

Since you now added the code to your question:

1. You have some typos there .. my bad I had them in my code as well: It should always be `OnPointerXY` instead of `OnPinterXY`.
2. Only keep the ones I had originally! There is no need to forward the call to the `Button` component. As long as you don't actively set the passed event to be "used" every handler will handle it on its own.
3. As already said you are still adding your listeners to `onClick` .. in order to attach to our new continuous calls it should rather look like

   ```
    public class ControlButtons : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField]  private ContinuousButton ClockwiseButton;
        [SerializeField] private ContinuousButton ForwardButton;
        [SerializeField] private ContinuousButton ReverseButton;
        [SerializeField] private ContinuousButton AntiClockwiseButton;
        [SerializeField] private ContinuousButton AscendButton;
        [SerializeField] private ContinuousButton DescendButton;

        public GameObject objectToPlace;

        private void Awake()
        {
            ClockwiseButton.whilePressed.AddListener(() => objectToPlace.transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, Vector3.up, 20 * Time.deltaTime));
            ForwardButton.whilePressed.AddListener(() => objectToPlace.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * 10));
            ReverseButton.whilePressed.AddListener(() => objectToPlace.transform.Translate(Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime * 10));
            AntiClockwiseButton.whilePressed.AddListener(() => objectToPlace.transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, Vector3.up, -20 * Time.deltaTime));
            AscendButton.whilePressed.AddListener(() => objectToPlace.transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * 10));
            DescendButton.whilePressed.AddListener(() => objectToPlace.transform.Translate(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * 10));
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much! when you say: "Then reference the desired method in whilePressed as you would with the onClick.", do you mean adding the behavior in the brackets of: whilePressed.Invoke(BEHAVIOR_HERE); Or simply in the while(true) loop? Thanks again!

Comment: No I mean like you would do it with the `onClick` .. either via drag and drop and select a method in the Inspector or using `AddListener` via code

Comment: Exactly, I want to use add listener, but where in the code I add the listener? Here is the line of code I used previously:  ForwardButton.onClick.AddListener(() => objectToPlace.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * 10));

Comment: Well, then as mentioned simply changed that to `ForwardButton.GetComponent<ContinuousButton>().whilePressed.AddListener(() => objectToPlace.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * 10));` that should do it

Comment: It doesn't work for some reason. Is this how the while should looks like? private IEnumerator WhilePressedRoutine()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            whilePressed.Invoke();
            _button.GetComponent<UpButtonScript>().whilePressed.AddListener(() => objectToPlace.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * 10));

            yield return null;
        }
    }

Comment: @user13305980 No ... you assign the callback only **once**. From a different script or via the Inspector .. not the same one. As said basically exactly the same way you would use [Button.onClick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdkrjCF0KCo) .. you assign the callback once and then it is automatically called every time the event is invoked ;) The invocation is the part the script above takes care of so you only need to assign the callback and watch it being called every frame while the button stays pressed

Comment: Hi, I tried copy-paste your script to the same folder of another script, and it doesn't work. Apparently it even breaks the function from the point I used it. I will try to write both scripts in the original question. I tried binding both scripts to a gameobject that contains the buttons. Many thanks regardless!

Comment: Hi I updated my answer using your code. What exactly does "it breaks" mean? Do you get any errors?

Comment: In Unity, when there is an error in a script, sometimes the commands of the script work fine until the problematic line.

Comment: Yes but usually in this case the "problem line" throws an error .. without knowing it it is a bit hard to help ;)

Comment: I feel like a complete idiot honestly. I tried using your code and create ContinuousButton members: [SerializeField]  private ContinuousButton ClockwiseButton; But I cannot attach my buttons to it in the Inspector. I also tried the previous approach: Creating regular buttons members, and use lines such as:  ForwardButton.GetComponent<ContinuousButton>().whilePressed.AddListener(() => objectToPlace.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * 10)); But this approach makes the buttons not to respond at all. Although I can attach them in the Inspector. So sorry about all the comments!